# A question on the Non-degenerated bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Prove that $<C(G), C(G)>$ is dual system with bilinear form $$\int_G \phi(x)\psi(x)dx $$ and $\psi(x),\psi(x)\in C(G)$

so here i was trying bilinear form im not getting how to prove non-degenerate

definition of the non-degenerate bilinear form is in Linear Integral Equations
By Raimer Kress

Comment: what is $G$ here ?

Comment: @Phil-W,,,measurable set

Comment: I'm guessing it's more than that, since you write C(G), you probably mean continuous functions on G right? So it has to be at least a topological space ?

Comment: @Phil-W...offcurse G is compact mesuarble and C is continuous fucntions on G

Comment: It would help people to help you if you give all the hypothesis you are considering here, and also the notations, and not let them be forced to guess what you mean. For instance, do you suppose that the measure on $G$ is Radon ?